# Why are APKs generated from Titanium-Alloy so large?

Tags: android, titanium-alloy

Even the "hello world" APK size is 10MB. Is this standard? Is there any way to reduce size?

Comment: Because you're not building a native app. You're building your app using different constructs that need to be interpreted and ultimately converted into valid Android code. To achieve this, a lot needs to be done and your code is written in such a way that works but is no where near optimal.

Comment: Thanks David ,but still, it seems very high in phonegap size weight is the same as a native

Comment: Thanks.....................................you are rigth

Answer (score 0):

With each build you're including the titanium runtime. This runtime is responsible for running your application cross-platform.

One way to reduce the size of the resulting APK is to through away unneeded modules.

Modules are referenced in two places.

First place is your project's `tiapp.xml` file. Check if you have any unused modules in the  section.

Second place is Titanium SDK installation. On OSX the `modules.json` is located inside: `~/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android`.
Modules references in modules.json are automatically included into the application. You can delete unused modules, but be careful. You will most likely lose some functionality, or it can crash the titanium runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
use the following code in tiapp.xml file.

 <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <manifest></manifest>
        <abi>armeabi</abi>
 </android>

Earlier we were using these 2 libraries.
A) armeabi 
B) armeabi-v7a

Each libraries using 5.2 Mb size on run time making the total build size 10.4 Mb.
So now we are using one armeabi libraries to restrict other armeabi-v7a libraries in the code which reduce the apk size to 5.2 Mb.
```